# Pygame : Repeating an action every x amount of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am a beginner in Python learning to build a simple game in Pygame where the player(monkey) tries to catch as many bananas as possible falling from the top of the screen.

My problem is how to get the bananas to spawn and fall individually every x time/seconds. Either they all spawn at once or if I use time.sleep, pauses the bananas midair. Even used threading after getting completely lost.

The relevant components of my code are as follows:

**catch_game**

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
# from background import Background
from monkey import Monkey
from banana import Banana

import functions

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.screen_width, settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Monkey Catch')

    monkey = Monkey(screen, settings)
    # background = Background((0, 0), screen)
    bananas = Group()

    functions.create_banana(screen, settings, bananas)

    while True:
        monkey.movement()
        functions.check_events(monkey)
        functions.update_screen(screen, settings, monkey, bananas)
        functions.update_banana(monkey, bananas)





run_game()
```

**banana**

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from random import randint


class Banana(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, settings):
        super(Banana, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.settings = settings


        self.image = pygame.image.load('E:\PycharmProjects\catch\images/banana.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.y = self.screen_rect.top
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.x = randint(0, 1150)

        self.speed = settings.banana_fallspeed

    def update(self):
        '''Banana falls down'''
        self.y += self.settings.banana_fallspeed

        self.rect.y = self.y
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def blit(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**functions**

```
import pygame
import sys
from banana import Banana
import threading
import time


def update_screen(screen, settings, monkey, bananas):
    screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
    # background.blit()
    monkey.blit()

    for banana in bananas:
        banana.update()
        bananas.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()


def keydown_events(event, monkey):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        monkey.moving_right = True
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        monkey.moving_left = True


def keyup_events(event, monkey):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        monkey.moving_right = False
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        monkey.moving_left = False


def check_events(monkey):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            keydown_events(event, monkey)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            keyup_events(event, monkey)


def create_banana(screen, settings, bananas):
        banana = Banana(screen, settings)
        bananas.add(banana)


def update_banana(monkey, bananas):
    '''kill bananas, collisions with monkey'''
    for banana in bananas.copy():
        if banana.rect.bottom >= 720:
            bananas.remove(banana)
    collision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(monkey, bananas, True)
    if collision:
        bananas.remove(banana)


        # time.sleep(2)
        # fall_interval = banana.threading.Timer(3, create_banana(screen, settings, bananas))
        # fall_interval.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use a timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create an [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html). e.g.:

```py
banana_delay = 500 # 0.5 seconds
banana_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(banana_event, banana_delay)
```

Note, in pygame customer events can be defined. Each event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to be between `pygame.USEREVENT` (24) and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (32). In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event, which spawns the bullets.

Create a new banana when the event occurs in the event loop:

```py
def check_events(screen, settings, bananas, monkey):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        # [...]

        if event.type == banana_event:
            create_banana(screen, settings, bananas)
```

The timer event can be stopped by passing 0 to the time parameter.

---

If you want spawn the bananas by a random time spawn, then you have to change the timespan (in milliseconds) randomly. Use [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=randint#random.randint) to generate random times:

```py
if event.type == banana_event:
    create_banana(screen, settings, bananas)
    banana_delay = random.randint(500, 3000) # random from 0.5 to 3 seconds
    pygame.time.set_timer(banana_event, banana_delay)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great advice! I was able to add the timer into check_events which worked perfectly. In addition I was actually researching this timer event earlier today, I was confused regarding that the USEREVENT was an numeric value, specifically between NOEVENT(0) and NUMEVENTS(32). Would you mind elaborating on this concept? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ngong123 See [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html). Each event type is associated to a unique ID in range from NOEVENT(0) to NUMEVENTS(32). The event ids in range from USEREVENT(24) to NUMEVENTS(32) are reserved for the "user" and can be used by the timer (see [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer))

Comment: I see. So I believe one can create their own event types USEREVENT + 0... up to USEREVENT +8, since NUMEVENTS(32) is the upper limit. Thank you for helping me get this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coroutines to run functions at the same time using `asyncio`. For example:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(1, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
    # around 2 seconds.)
    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

If you create a new task for each banana, you should be able to get a few on screen at different times.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: Please respect that the question is tagged [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news)

Comment: Appreciate the advice! Though harder to interpret, will look into coroutines as a technique moving on.